# 404 error while trying to submit form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to submit a form for calls to my database using laravel eloquent but each time I try, it always shoots up a 404 error.

Here is my `web.php`

```
Route::get('/calls/newCall', 'CallsController@newCall');
Route::get('/calls/addNewCall', 'CallsController@create');
Route::resource('new_calls', 'CallsController');
```

This is my `CallsController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\new_calls;

class CallsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function viewCall($id){ // the id in the url

        $new_calls = new_calls::find($id);

        return view('calls.viewCall')->with('new_calls', $new_calls);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('calls.addNewCall');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validate data
        $this->validate($request, array(
           'terminal_id'=> 'required',
           'terminal_name'=> 'required',
        ));

        // store in the database
        $call = new new_calls;
        $call->terminal_id = $request->terminal_id;
        $call->terminal_name = $request->terminal_name;

        $call->save();

        //redirect
        return redirect()->route('new_calls.show', $call->id);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my form

```
<form action="CallController@new_calls.store" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="terminal_id">{{ __('Terminal ID') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="terminal_id" id="terminal_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Terminal ID" style="padding: 20px;" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="width: 100%;">
            <label for="terminal_name">{{ __('Terminal name') }}</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="terminal_name" id="terminal_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Terminal Name" style="padding: 20px;" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 16px; border: 0;">{{ __('Submit') }}</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an HTML context where the form action is literally the URL you are trying to submit the form to.  You aren't using the blade template syntax or calling any Laravel function in the form action assignment.  You also aren't defining the route action correctly.

You would either use the route name:

```
route('new_calls.store');
```

Or you would use the action:

```
action('CallsController@store');
```

You are using a combination of the two.

Replace your form action correctly:

```
<form action="{{ route('new_calls.store') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: thanks for your response... the problem is now fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form action="{{ action('CallController@store') }}" method="post">
```

Source: [URLs For Controller Actions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#urls-for-controller-actions)

Comment: thanks for your response... the problem is now fixed